# how to make angularjs loop run continuously without error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written a loop in angularJS with delay and I want to run it continuously. Here I tried a while loop including the following code but due to running infinite time it gave me error, but my main aim is to run the following code continuously (like infinite loop)

```
angular.forEach($scope.articles, function (art) {
  promise = promise.then(function () {
    return $timeout(5000);
  });
})
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve? Can u explain the task at hand?

Comment: I am basically developing a UI for notice board where I have to display the notices in a single division with delay and once all the notices are displayed it should restart displaying it and this should run continuously. So I am stuck with how to run it continuously once the foreach loop gets finished.

Comment: Why dont you use setInterval (something like this)
`setInterval(function(){ 
    for(var i=0; i<10;i++){
        console.log(i); 
    } 
}, 2000);` If you are working specifically with angular you can use $interval

Comment: Thanks Rahul it worked for me :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use a `$timeout`, in your case you need `$interval`

```
$interval(function(){ 
   for(var i=0; i < 5;i++){ 
      console.log("I am a Bear"); 
   } 
}, 5000);
```

In angularJS you have to use `$interval` instead `setInterval()` because you could have problems with the two-way data binding. 

Even is a good practive to destroy the $interval.

**FULL EXAMPLE:**

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
       .controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);

myCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$interval'];
function myCtrl($scope, $interval) {
    var myInterval = $interval(function(){
      for(var i=0; i < 5;i++){ 
        console.log("I am a Bear"); 
      } 
    }, 5000);

    $scope.$on('$destroy', function () { 
      $interval.cancel(myInterval); 
    });
}
```

Check angular [$interval docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)

Answer (score -2):

I think this is pretty strong antipattern. You're probably better off looking into *listeners*, like `$on`, `$watch`, and the like.

Or if you must, into *debouncers*.

Comment: to listen to what? Answer doesn't really make much sense without more context

Comment: ask and you shall receive