# Never ending loop through array in AngularJS + setTimeout after each iteration

Tags: angularjs, settimeout, infinite-loop

How can I achieve a never ending loop in AngularJS?

my try:

```
item_list = [{'id':1, 'photo':'path/src'}, {'id':2, 'photo':'path/src'}, {'id':3, 'photo':'path/src'}];

item_list.map(function(item) {
    setTimeout( function () {
         setCoverImage(item.photo);
    }, 5000);
)
```

I'm going to change cover image using `setCoverImage()` every 5 s using data from `item_list`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make angularjs loop run continuously without error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42330469/how-to-make-angularjs-loop-run-continuously-without-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should use AngularJS's [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval). Then simply increment a counter and use it to access the current element's `photo` property in your controller and use [ng-src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) to reflect that URL in your img tag.

```
<img ng-src="{{myCtrl.item_list[myCtrl.currentIndex].photo}}">
```

Be careful that you never assign to the counter a value that would not correspond to an element in your array.

```
if ((that.currentIndex + 1) >= that.item_list.length)
```

See full example below

```js
angular.module('appModule', []).controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$interval', function($scope, $interval) {
  this.item_list = [{
    'id': 1,
    'photo': 'https://i.pinimg.com/736x/32/76/a2/3276a2111c65b2131ef834736f47162b--birthday-kitten-birthday-hats.jpg'
  }, {
    'id': 2,
    'photo': 'http://img.playbuzz.com/image/upload/f_auto,fl_lossy,q_auto/cdn/154cb38e-55e3-4294-bffe-6906b6a41a6b/c33bcc8b-40be-49c9-bad1-ee85f8275189.jpg'
  }, {
    'id': 3,
    'photo': 'http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-J4ioK5aRks8/Tx8d9D5K54I/AAAAAAAAABM/iTL4sbsNYmc/w1200-h630-p-k-no-nu/Surprised+and+serious+kitten.jpg'
  }];
  var that = this;
  this.currentIndex = 0;
  $interval(function() {
    if ((that.currentIndex + 1) >= that.item_list.length) {
      that.currentIndex = 0;
    } else {
      that.currentIndex++;
    }
  }, 5000);
}])

angular.bootstrap(window.document, ['appModule'], {
  strictDi: true
});
```

```html
<div ng-controller="MyController as myCtrl">
  <img ng-src="{{myCtrl.item_list[myCtrl.currentIndex].photo}}">
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) service of AngularJS like this:

```
$interval( function () {
     setCoverImage(item.photo);
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject `$interval` service in your controller/service (whatever) and then you can use something like this:

```
 let currentPhotoIdx = 0;
 const maxAvailablePhotoIdx = item_list.length - 1;
 $interval(() => {
    setCoverImage(item.photo[currentPhotoIdx]);
    currentPhotoIdx === maxAvailablePhotoIdx ? currentPhotoIdx = 0 : currentPhotoIdx++;
 }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution to `$interval` is `$timeout`:

```
function setCoverImageLoop(photo) {
    $timeout(function () {
        setCoverImage(photo);
        setCoverImageLoop(photo);
    }, 5000);
}

item_list = [{'id':1, 'photo':'path/src'}, {'id':2, 'photo':'path/src'}, {'id':3, 'photo':'path/src'}];

item_list.map(function(item) {
     setCoverImageLoop(item.photo);
});
```

This is probably a bit old-school, and mainly for people who preferred coming from `setTimeout`.

Comment: `$timeout` will NOT loop endless. On the other hand, the recursive call makes the trick, tough you get a verbose and "hard-to-maintain-in-future" code. Keeping that in mind, it's a valid solution

Comment: Indeed. Mostly it comes from `setTimeout` being used to measure the time between frames with graphics output, but given that `$interval` returns a promise which is notified on each iteration anyway, I suspect my solution is entirely redundant.